Set of finite dimensional vector spaces.
Is the set of all finite-dimensional vector spaces well-defined? I know, this is not true if the vector spaces are not finite-dimensional, but I was wondering if that assumption might make a difference.

No, this is not a set. If it were, you could construct the set of all finite sets, which is not a set.

Thusle is correct, but your idea is not far off. Up to isomorphism there is only a set of finite dimensional vector spaces (if you fix the field, say vector spaces over the reals). That is, there is a set $X$ of vector spaces such that every finite dimensional vector space is isomorphic to one in $X$. Without the restriction on the dimension this is no longer true.

If this is the kind of thing you were asking about I am happy to turn my comment into an answer with a few more details.

Thank you for your answers. I think both are useful. However, I know that we can define a set containing all the finite-dimensional vector spaces up to isomorphism. Maybe this can be turned into an answer (@Mark Kamsma) because it might be useful for someone else. Thanks again. :)

Turning some comments into an answer.
Firstly, there are "too many" finite dimensional vector spaces to contain them all in a set. For example, for every singleton set $S$ we can view it as a zero-dimensional vector space by interpreting the unique element in $S$ as zero. It is an easy exercise to show that there is a proper class of singleton sets.
Of course, all these singletons are isomorphic as vector spaces, so we are not really looking at different vector spaces. If we only care about vector spaces up to isomorphism then there is a positive answer to your question.
Fix the field $K$ over which you wish to consider vector spaces (e.g., $K = \mathbb{R}$). Then we can consider the set
$$
A = \{ K^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \},
$$
where $K^n$ is the usual $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space. Then for every finite dimensional $K$-vector space $V$ there is some $V' \in A$ such that $V \cong V'$. So we have a set of all finite dimensional $K$-vector spaces, up to isomorphism.
The restriction on the dimension is important here. There is no set of all $K$-vector spaces, not even up to isomorphism. That is because for every cardinal $\kappa$ there is a $K$-vector space of dimension $\kappa$. Since there is a proper class of cardinals, there is a proper class of isomorphism classes of $K$-vector spaces.

(Just adding on...) In categorical terms, the category of finite dimensional vector spaces is not a small category, however its skeleton is a set.  Since every category is equivalent to its skeleton, it's what is called an essentially small category
