Do all finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces form a set?
The question is as in the title. For instance, could we define a universal inner product function with its domain being $\bigcup_H(H\times H)$, where the union is over all finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, and mapping any element $(\psi,\phi)$ in its domain to their inner product $\langle\psi,\phi\rangle$? I would guess no, but I don't know where to look for a formal argument for this.

Hint: There is no set of all finite sets.

For every set $x$ there is a Hilbert space $H$ of dimension $0$ such that $x\in H$: namely, $H={x}$, with sum $x+x=x$, action of $\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb C$) $\lambda\cdot x=x$ and scalar product $\langle x,x\rangle =0$. So if you had a set $V$ that contains all the finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, then $\bigcup V$ would be a universal set, and no such set exists. In most cases, with similar ideas it can be proved that the class of all the bagoongies who are bagoongi-isomorphic to some fixed bagoongi $T$ is proper.

Even if it were legitimate to take such a union, you would still have to deal with the problem that any particular set can have many different Hilbert space structures, so you would not have a well-defined function.

This is very similar to a recent question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4991710/set-of-finite-dimensional-vector-spaces/

Great, thanks. How would a formal argument go if we excluded 0-dimensional spaces?

0-dimensional spaces are kind of pathological for the problem that motivated my question, and can be safely excluded, but I think the above argument can be easily modified by taking for every set x the vector space ${(x,\lambda):,\lambda\in \mathbb{C}}$, defining $(x,\lambda_1)+(x,\lambda_2):=(x,\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$, $\eta(x,\lambda):=(x,\eta\lambda)$, and $\langle (x,\lambda),(x,\eta)\rangle:=\overline{\lambda}\eta$. Then the set of all finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces would include $(x,1)$ for every set $x$, which is not posisble.

@user60121 That's right, there is nothing special about 0-dimensional spaces to get a proper class, they're just the easiest example. There is a proper class of Hilbert spaces (even vector spaces) in any given dimension, for example using the trick you described.
